# Cannot retrieve sbt dependencies without internet

Tags: sbt

I'm trying to retrieve the sbt dependencies offline.

Since `sbt` always needs some kind of dependencies to work I'm looking for any solution to evaluate the build.sbt or any other files that might have dependencies and give their module information.

A simple solution would be to parse build.sbt and retrieve that info with a regex but there are multiple issues related to it such as:

- the dependencies can be appended strings
- the values can be in variables/values
- multiple files can contain those dependencies
- sub-projects can also contains the dependencies

To solve this I would like to run and truly offline sbt plugin that would not need to retrieve all the project dependencies jars and would only parse the dependencies and give them to my program.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Note: I would be fine supplying some needed jars to sbt to run, but I cannot support the retrieval of all the project dependencies jars.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$ sbt "set offline := true" run
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is going to help you just sharing..

One of the other way to resolve dependencies is to download all the project dependencies and copy them to  .ivy2 cache folder under C:\Users\your profile.ivy2\cache

if you are working on a project where more than one person is working  setup local artifactory(I am using this and it is working well for me ) and resolve from local.

Comment: That is still not a solution. I already had tried with both `.ivy2` and `.sbt` pre-setup but sbt still goes online for reasons.